# google Authenticator For SSH server

Tags: two-factor-authentication

Here, I have added the Google authenticator to my Yacto build for two-factor authentication when taking ssh and also enbaled **KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes** in the sshd configuration. After restarting the service, I tried to login, but authentication was not asked; only the user name and password were asked. Should I configure another option?

I have enabled **KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes** in the sshd configuration. After restarting the service, I tried to login, but authentication was not asked; only the user name and password were asked. Should I configure another option?